# "hide" an encrypted partition on a USB drive

Tags: partition, truecrypt

I have a USB drive with two partitions.  The first is unencrypted and has the truecrypt binary.  The second is encrypted (with truecrypt) and has sensitive data.

When I plug in my USB drive the encrypted partition shows up in Windows.  I do not want it to show up.  I can remove the drive letter, but if I plug it into another PC it shows up again.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=hidden-volume

But if you still want to hide partition take a look at that http://agnipulse.com/2011/08/create-hidden-partition-usb-flash-drive/

google doesn't hurt :D

Comment: Already looked at hidden volume, and it's not what I'm looking for.  I'll have a look at the second link.  Thanks.

Comment: Although FbinstTool creates a hidden partition, I have to export files to access it.  This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This link may also help.

http://agnipulse.com/2011/11/partition-usb-flash-drive/

It is not exactly an hidden partition, but due to certain limitations of Windows, it can be used as a hidden partition.

With this method it is easy to access the data on the hidden partition.